# SQL Server RAM Usage: Multiple Databases vs. One Big Database

Tags: sql-server, database, memory, ram, multiple-databases

This questions is strictly about estimating RAM usage and not about database design.

Assumptions:

- Data in multiple data sets is not related to each other, so there are no issues splitting into multiple DBs
- Data schema is the same, so there are also no issues combining all into 1 big DB
- There are millions of records in each data set
- If going with multiple DBs, there could be 30-50 DBs
- Usage (number of queries) will be identical whether its 1 big DB or multiple smaller DBs

Would running multiple databases in above described scenario require SQL Server to consume more RAM than running a single big DB ?